# How to include image in a animated chart bar with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, gganimate

How to include images in the bars, in an animated chart bar with R?
The animated chart is based on this code:
*https://github.com/amrrs/animated_bar_charts_in_R*

I would like to add flags to each bar, as in:
*https://www.technologyreview.com/2020/03/27/950263/the-covid-19-pandemic-in-two-animated-charts/*

But my flags are personalized, so the package *"GGIMAGE"* doesn't work. I want to upload my own images.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't ignore some concern of yours, but if it is only that you have your own image files and don't want to use `ggimage::geom_flag`, then `ggimage` might still be useful to you - you just have to provide the path to your own image as a parameter to `ggimage::geom_image`.
It should be easy if you name the flag images simply the same as your `country_name`+ *.png* .

Unfortunately I know little about that animation code and the example you shared, so you might need to tamper a little to get the positioning right :)

```
library(ggimage)

anim <- ggplot(gdp_formatted, [...]) +
  [...] +
  ggimage::geom_image(
    aes(
      # x = rank,
      y = value,
      image = file.path(<path_to_local_folder>, paste0(country_name,'.png')),
      # size = ...
  )
)
```

Fair warning, the `size` aesthetics param was really annoying to me and only by pure luck I got it under control (in my use case, images had different dimensions and needed to be rescaled).
I'd suggest to preprocess them so they fit and just not bother with this part :)